# A "fuse" for overvoltage

Tags: voltage

I'm an American living abroad in the land of 220v with various 110v appliances. Here in the Philippines, for some wacky colonial reason, the plugs are the same two flat prongs as the US, but the wall provides 220v power. I have a transformer, so this is all fine and well as long as I'm careful to not plug it into the wall. Always careful. (Which of course I am not.)

What I would like is a simple adapter plug that can go on the end of each 110v appliance (and never come off) with a fuse inside that will pop if it is ever accidentally plugged into the 220v socket. Obviously, fuses are for current and don't work for overvoltage, but I'm not sure if there's another term.

Do you know if a product like this exists? Do you think there's perhaps a way to DIY one if not?

Comment: Consider bolting on something really cheap, like https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0058EG0KC , to each of your existing 110 V appliances. This will make them ***incompatible*** with your wall outlets. Then add custom adapters that transform 220 V into 110 V to some of your wall outlets that can accept those *hinky* EU plugs you've then attached. The idea is to make them physically incompatible so that you don't make any more mistakes.

Comment: @jonk That's not a bad idea. Thanks! I was also thinking this could be a very popular product for anyone who's burnt out an appliance (in my circles this is everyone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack anyway. Best option would be to identify devices that do not support 220V and wire a different plug only available on your converters.

You can get a [**varistor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor).

This is a component that starts conducting above a certain voltage.
As seen here with the blue line, above +/-300 volts, current will quickly rise.
[image: varistor]

You **must** use a fuse or circuitbreaker in series with the varistor in order to disconnect the circuit when the varistor is conducting. You also have to use a varistor rated for enough power to prevent the varistor to blow before the fuse. Many devices will already contain varistors to reduce the effects of transients.

**Beware, varistors can [explode violently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzSjK9Nz44w).**

Another option would be to use a voltage monitoring relay. These are more expensive, but are less destructive.

Comment: I guess that a varistor might not handle the energy (power*t) until the fuse blows...

Comment: That is why varistor must be able to absorb more energy that needed to blow the fuse. Just have a big varistor and a small fuse and you will be on the safe side.

Comment: @next-hack Well, yes. But you can get very large ones.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what I was thinking. So the varistor and the fuse are in series on one side of the circuit? (Just after one prong of the plug?) [PS I know I'm an amateur so I won't be willy nilly with this!]

Comment: @Tom The varistor will be parallel to the consumer, after the series fuse. But beware, the varistor **will explode violently** if it's not big enough or used with the wrong fuse. So please consider a safer approach!

Comment: Thanks for your safety concerns. These are well noted. What I would really like is a consumer product that I could use and even resell (a lot of people have this problem here). But I haven't seen anything like that on the market. Maybe the explosion risk is why.